# Wrapping array method for cleaner more dry code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to clean up my code and figure out a way to pass the array method `.all?`. Here is the code:

```
if <condition>
  parent_1.children.all? {|c| <condition>} ? result_of_true : result_of_false
else
  parent_2.children.all? {|c| <condition>} ? result_of_true : result_of_false
end
```

They are both using `.all? {|c| <condition>}`. I'm trying to get it so I can shorten this line up and though maybe I could do something like create a scope on each of the children and use that, maybe create a `proc` and use that?

I've tried the following:

```
def new_all?
  proc { |*args| args.all? {|c| c.attribute} }
end

if <condition>
  parent_1.child.new_all? ? result_of_true : result_of_false
else
  parent_2.child.new_all? ? result_of_true : result_of_false
end

# return example: [false, false, true]
```

or maybe something on the child class like:

```
def self.new_all?
  all? {|c| <condition>}
end
```

There has to be a way to do this. I'm hoping something outside of having to work with the actual `Array` class.

This seems to return an array of the results but obviously not a single boolean value that you would expect from `all?`.

## Update

There were some great solutions to my question, most of which, I understood and was previously aware of; although did a poor job at explaining that in my question.

The answer to my question that I was looking for was answered by @Stefan when mentioning [association extensions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions). I originally didn't have success trying to implement it but then began to deep dive into rails `scopes` and how they function. Was able to understand a little more about extensions on scopes.

Comment: What is `result_of_true`, `result_of_false`, and `condition`? Are those methods or variables? When they are calculated, do they depend on the context of where the block is called, or do they depend on the `parents` or the `child`?

Comment: Where does `child` come from? Is it a `has_many` association on parent? If so, you could define a method on the proxy object via [association extensions](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions). (and in that case it should also be "children", not "child")

Comment: @Stefan. `Children` ARE a `has_many` relationship. Any suggestion on how to do that. I tried applying a `association extension` and also tried through using `scope`. However, it didn't work as expected. Maybe because I was using an `Array` method on an `Object`?

Comment: @Nappy can you show your attempts?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just define a simple method and then use a one line ternary?

```
def new_all? (x)
 x.all? {|item| <condition>} ? <result of true> : <result of false>
end

<other_condition> ? new_all?(a) : new_all?(b)
```

Comment: I did think about that. Wondering if there is a more "elegant" way. Maybe there isn't though and this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of simplifying (hah!) the code would be to extract the duplicate code from the branches of the conditional expression and move it outside of the conditional expression:

```ruby
if <condition>
  parent_1
else
  parent_2
end.child.all? {|c| <condition>} ? result_of_true : result_of_false
```

By the way, I find the mix of conditional expression and conditional operator hard to read. In fact, I find the conditional operator hard to read in general. It is also completely unnecessary in Ruby. The conditional operator is required in C, because it is an operator and thus an expression whereas the conditional statement is, well, a statement. But in Ruby, the conditional expression is already an expression, so there is no need for the conditional operator.

So, I would probably write it more like this:

```ruby
if if condition
     parent_1
   else
     parent_2
   end.child.all? { |c| condition }
  result_of_true
else
  result_of_false
end
```

or maybe

```ruby
if if condition then parent_1 else parent_2 end.child.all? { |c| condition }
  result_of_true
else
  result_of_false
end
```

However, this screams for extracting some of the stuff into methods or at least variables.

Comment: While logically and syntactically correct the `if if` makes me feel uncomfortable is so many ways :)